# Getting maximum value of shapekeys eval_time(python)?

Tags: python, shape-keys

Say, I have an object with multiple shapekeys on it.

Unchecking "relative" option gives me "evaluation time" parameter.
And the last shapekey has exact maximum value of the "evaluation time" parameter

How can I get this maximum value via python?
[image: (screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If the keys are absolute, rather than relative, they are maintained in sorted order, by time frame.  If you want to find the last key from the active object, use

```py
bpy.context.active_object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[-1]
```

to access the last shape key in the sequence.  It will be the one with the maximum value.  The field that contains the values is `frame`, so the maximum value will be found as

```py
bpy.context.active_object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[-1].frame
```

Obviously, you can replace `bpy.context.active_object` by whatever object you want to find the value for.